# calculating distance using latitude & longitude

Tags: r, geo

I am calculating the distance covered by bike riders. I have the latitude and longitude info for their starting point and end point. I looked up earlier solutions but using distHaversine with Geosphere package did not work for me. Adding that code here as well.

```
DF <- data.frame(Start.Lat = c(40.74178, 40.72132, 40.79948, 40.75020, 40.71413, 40.74312, 40.72904, 40.74780, 40.69779, 40.72955), Start.Lon = c(-74.00150, -74.01006, -73.95561, -73.99093, -73.95234, -73.98215, -73.99405, -73.97344, -73.97374, -73.98057), End.Lat =c(40.74174, 40.70380, 40.79377, 40.76133, 40.71335, 40.76096, 40.71894, 40.73705, 40.75110, 40.73493), End.Lon = c(-73.99416, -74.00839, -73.97189, -73.97982, -73.94910, -73.96724, -73.99266 , -73.99009, -73.94074, -73.99201))
```

Code where I tried to use geosphere:

```
install.packages("geosphere")
library(geosphere)
distm(cbind(DF$Start.Lon, DF$Start.Lat), cbind(DF$End.Lon, DF$End.Lat), fun = distHaversine)
```

Error message: (only get this error when I use my full dataset consisting of 30,000 data points)

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.7 Gb

Comment: The c function is making 1 long vector.  Try replacing the c with cbind. This should create a 2 column matrix.

Comment: also setting `distHaversine` may mean you lose some small amount of accuracy. The default algorithm may be better if accuracy is an issue and I don't think there's much difference in performance.

Comment: Thank you so much. The cbind works with the small sample dataset I created but not with my bigger dataset with 30,000 observations. I get an error message that says,

Comment: @Seema, The error is pretty, Your 30,000 data points are creating some very large data structures.   The solution is either get a bigger computer or perform the calculation in a series of smaller steps.